# get django variable by javascript variable

Tags: javascript, django

I want to get variable stored in Django admin by using JavaScript variable for ex:

```
var x = 2;
console.log("{{product.0}}") //by this I get data from admin
console.log( "{{product." + x + "}}"  ) //but by this it shows couldn't parse reminder  +x+
```

I want that I get my data by using that x variable

Comment: How would that even work? JavaScript is evaluated at the clients machine and the template is rendered by Django at the server. What you want to do is not possible. If x is supposed to be 2 just write it there. If you want to get the data from server make an ajax request.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat what i have given is you is just a ex but in my project all this is in a loop and x is changing its value and i want data corresponding to that value from databse so its not actually possible to write 2 there....Someone please look at this

Comment: As I said in my comment it is **not possible**. Firstly Django will not evaluate / run your JavaScript (why would it need to). Secondly it is best **not** to render from Django into javascript to prevent any XSS attacks. For whatever reason you need to have data in javascript you can: 1) Render the data in the html and hide it using hidden attribute or similar. 2) Make an ajax request to the server to get any needed data.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the variable on render time, you want to make a POST request to your django server to request the data.

If you do know the variable x on render time you can render your data onto your templates directly as javascript.